# Conditional type 2 with an adverb of time

Tags: adverbs, conditionals

Is it possible to use conditional type 2 with an adverb of time and would it change its meaning?

For example:

> What would you do if you lost your job?

comparing to:

> What would you do if you lost your job **next week**?

Comment: The inclusion of a temporal adjunct is fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct: In fact, all of the following are correct.

What **would** you do if you **lost** your job?

What **would** you do if you **lost** your job next week?

What **will** you do if you **los**e your job?

What **will** you do if you **lose** your job next week?

Comment: But "if you lost" implies less probability..something unlikely to happen. They are different

Comment: @BM Sadri They are different but they are correct.